# can we personally block particular users so that we become invisible to each other on HSE?

Tags: feature-request

some posters bait all the time and it would be good to become mutually invisible with them, like on Twitter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is currently not possible, even though it's a long-standing feature request: [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/295232) (from 2009!). It was declined, but since then there has been a [reply from a former staff member](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309160/295232) that they were going to reconsider this. However, that's a long time ago already so I have no idea if that is still reflecting the current situation.